# How to reconnect to running emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, intellij-idea

When I connect the phone to a USB port, in order to be able to use the phone, I have to kill/start ADB server from the console via `adb kill-server` & `adb start-server`. 
After this, Intellij losts connection to the already running emulator.

I know that if I restart an emulator, I will get the connection back. Is there a faster way to simply reconnect IntelliJ to already running emulator?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach to already running emulator via a "cloud" button in Android Logcat pane:

[image]

Sometimes this button needs to be toggled several times to have effect.

In IDEA 10.5 there is now a button that also attaches debugger to already running Android app: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/05/new-in-105-attach-debugger-to-a-running-android-process/

Comment: After I get disconnected, a logcat windows becomes gray!!!! I can show you an image, if needed. And I really hoped this would work.